# QT Creator cannot find "objbase.h" when invoking nmake

Tags: qt, c++17, qt5

When attempting to build my Qt project with MSVC2015 64bit for Windows 10, I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Ole2.h:37: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'objbase.h': No such file or directory
...
NMAKE:-1: error: U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
NMAKE:-1: error: U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

-- when nmake is invoked during the build process.
This exact same error also occurs for the example project "addressbook".

It appears to be some kind of toolchain issue, but I can compile a Qt Widget project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 if I point VS at my Qt installation.

I'm not sure what I need to do from here, since I already tried a reinstall of Qt. I have seen that putting things in Program Files is generally a bad idea, but that doesn't seem to be the issue in this specific case.

It appears to be part of the Windows SDK, if Google leads me right. However, I did not have to download the Windows SDK separately in order to compile my project and run it successfully before. (For context, the project's been developed for a few months and this problem only emerged a week or so ago).

**My QT Installation:**

- Kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2015 64bit
- Version: Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2015 64bit
- Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 17.3.32811.315 (amd64)

**Things That Have Happened Before My Build Attempt:**

- I recently reinstalled Qt 5.15.2 in an effort to resolve a similar missing file issue.
- The company's recently had issues with Microsoft Intune deleting applications. Maybe it hit the Windows SDK too.

**Attempts at Solving the Issue**

1. Reinstallation of Qt 5.15.2

- Expected: My project building without errors. Result: This error.

2. Search of file system for objbase.h

- Expected: Finding the file. Result: I did not find the file.

I'm newish at Qt, so I didn't want to try anything more esoteric lest I made things worse than before.

Update: MinGW 64 bit works for the example Qt projects, but I'd still like to use MSVC2015 if possible. It doesn't work for my project because I use some MSVC specific pre-processor flags in my source.

Update 2: I attempted to re-download MSVC 2015 from Visual Studio's website, using their Build Tools installer. While the installation successfully finished, I got no change from before -- it still can't find that "objbase.h" file. It's *supposed* to be in the Windows Kits directory under Include//um , I think.

Comment: I have not been able to build my cpp project since 1/13 when MS screwed up and had Window's defender delete a bunch of stuff from my start menu. I am wondering if it deleted more than I thought.

Comment: It could be that you are experiencing a similar issue -- I found it very suspicious that the missing header file problem started just as Microsoft Intune was reported to be deleting other peoples' files (including things like Chrome, Firefox, etc). The project compiled without issue before the Intune situation, so there's a temporal correlation there.

Comment: I just reinstalled the Windows SDK (in my instance `Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0)` through Visual Studio installer and it fixed my issue. Now I am wondering what else got wiped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm posting the solution here for others.

My issue was that, for reasons that are unclear to me, VS Studio Build Tools would not actually remove the SDK in question if I unchecked its box in the Modify screen. You can tell if this is happening by checking the disk size difference of the upcoming installation in the lower right of the screen -- if it won't remove the SDK, that size will be +0 bytes (assuming you don't check or uncheck any other box).

In order to properly reinstall the SDK version, I had to go to "Add or remove programs" and find the SDK there, uninstall it, restart my computer just for safety, and **then** go to VS Build Tools and install that SDK version. I had to do a "fake" uninstall with VS Build Tools (basically, uncheck the now-deleted SDK and click "Modify", allowing it to do the installation and download steps) before I could actually install the SDK again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, in my case, the objbase.h file was deleted due to the issue with Windows Defender deleting random files. I was able to reinstall the version of Windows SDK that was using and this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall the SDK? I used the Visual Studio Build Tools installer and told it to install my version of the SDK (10.0.19041.0), but that didn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps it saw the folder and thought that it didn't need to install anything.

Comment: I went into the Installer, clicked on modify, selected `Individual components`, unchecked the version of Windows SDK that i had installed, then clicked Modify. Once it was done what it was doing I closed out of it and went back in to the installer and installed the same version of the SDK that was installed previously.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me. "objbase.h" remains missing from the SDK. Unless I'm looking in the wrong directory entirely and it's a PATH issue where QT hasn't been given the right folders to look in. Do you know where "objbase.h" is supposed to be?

Comment: I believe that this was the location, but i do not know for sure as I have fixed the error. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um`